# Toggling MenuItem visibility to a GridControl's SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `GirdControl` on my WPF that is bound to objects of type `NoteFrontEnd`. There is a property in `NoteFrontEnd` named `NoteType` that I want to use as the source of a visibility binding in a `MenuItem`.

The user must right-click on one of the `NoteFrontEnd` objects from the `GridControl`, and based on its `NoteType` property, either show or hide the `MenuItem` with `Header="Process Item"`.

The `GridControl` and `MenuItem` are defined in xaml as:

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="GridCtrl"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BaseDashboardDataSource}"
                    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="None">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        ...
        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="NoteType"  FieldName="NoteType" Header="Type" />
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                        <CompositeCollection>

                            ...

                            <!--Menu Item to toggle visibility of-->
                            <MenuItem Header="Process Item"
                                    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=GridCtrl, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource GVItemToVis}}"     
                                        Command="{...}">
                            </MenuItem>

                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                </ContextMenu>
            </dxg:TableView.ContextMenu>
        </dxg:TableView>
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

My ViewModel is defined as such:

```
public class NoteViewModel : DashboardViewModelBase
{
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<NoteFrontEnd> BaseDashboardDataSource { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<BrokerNoteFrontEnd> SelectedItems
    {
        get { return _selectedItems; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItems == value) return;
            _selectedItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public NoteViewModel(...) {
        ...
        BaseDashboardDataSource = new ObservableCollection<NoteFrontEnd>();
    }
}
```

And `NoteFrontEnd` as:

```
public class NoteFrontEnd
{
    public string NoteType { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the below error though:

```
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=GridCtrl'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItems;...
```

I have tried other bindings like the below but got the same error:

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource GVItemToVis}}"
```

How can I get this binding to work?

Answer (score 0):

A context menu is a separate window. It is in a different namescope to your gridcontrol.

I suggest you:

Associate the context menu with the row each NoteFrontEnd is in rather than the entire grid.

NoteFrontEnd should be a viewmodel that implements inotifypropertychanged. Even if you have no changes you want to notify about. Always bind to an object implements inpc and avoid the possibility of a memory leak from bindings.

That then means you can get to the datacontext of that row using either the below or a variant:

```
     <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

That means the datacontext is pointed to the note which is templated into the row clicked.

You can then put a command in your NoteFrontEnd does whatever this is supposed to do.

You could also bind visibility of this menuitem to a property that is based on frontend and encapsulates whatever your logic is.

I suggest you (instead) consider using the canexecute part of icommand and return false when the user isn't supposed to click this option. That way the entry will still be there in the context menu but disabled and greyed.